# Elixir Ecto: Could someone give an example of Ecto.Multi.run/5

Tags: elixir, ecto

The [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#run/5) state

```
run(t, name, module, function, args) :: t when function: atom, args: [any]
```

> Similar to `run/3`, but allows to pass module name, function and
>   arguments. The function should return either `{:ok, value}` or `{:error,`
>   `value}`, and will receive changes so far as the first argument
>   (prepened to those passed in the call to the function).

But I'm unsure how to use this. Let's say I have this function I want to run inside of `Ecto.Multi`:

```
def some_fun(value, other_value) do
  case value do
    nil -> {:error, other_value}
    _ -> {:ok, other_value}
  end
end
```

How would that work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `value` to be the "changes so far" and `other_value` is a value you're specifying when calling `Multi.run/5`. In that case, if your function is in a module named `Foo`:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def some_fun(value, other_value) do
    case value do
      nil -> {:error, other_value}
      _ -> {:ok, other_value}
    end
  end
end
```

then your `Multi.run/5` call will be:

```
Multi.run(multi, name, Foo, :some_fun, [other_value])
```

which is equivalent to the following `Multi.run/3` call:

```
Multi.run(multi, name, fn value -> Foo.some_fun(value, other_value) end)
```